# Is it possible in flutter to get ID of an iPhone device to verify it's the same device?

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, device, udid

I would like to verify that my App working on the same device.

Below is a description of the process:

1. I read the ID from device on SignUp and store it on cloud DB.
2. Each SignIn (email + Password) read again the ID and compare to ID from DB.
3. If they are not equal -> exit

The problem is that after upgrade App version the device ID is not the same!

I tried some plugins they have the same status.

Any idea to verify its the same device, without SMS verification?

Comment: You can store a value in the keychain.  This will survive app delete/install but not device erase

Comment: Where iOS store the data wit flutter_keychain? on the device?
Android store on google drive?

Comment: The keychain is a secure on-device store.  There is no Android equivalent as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Device Info Plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) plugin?

You can get the current device information from within the Flutter application

**Example**

```
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';
DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();

AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
print('Android ID ${androidInfo.androidId}');

IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
print('Ios ID ${iosInfo.identifierForVendor}');
```

Comment: Thanks I tested this ID and it will be changed in the next App version

Comment: When your app is released, Identifier for vendor will only change if the user deletes and reinstalls your app. It won't change if they simply update the version over the top